# Problem with AddFromString function of CodeModule in VBA

Tags: vba

I try to add code to VBA CodeModule using the AddFromString function of VBComponents CodeModule. However there is always a extra "()" added to the code if the string I add involve lib and _(line continue). Can someone give me a hint about what is wrong and how to fix? Thanks.

Here is the code.

```
Sub test()

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\test.docm")
Set wrdModule = wrdDoc.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule

myStr = "Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib ""xyz"" _" + vbNewLine + "(x)"
wrdModule.AddFromString(myStr)
wrdApp.Documents.Save
wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit

End Sub
```

In Module1, I get:

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "xyz" _
(x)
()    <- extra "()" causing compiler error
```

Comment: Clearly that's a bug. Since they are not going to fix it you need to avoid using the line-continuation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not to recognize the continuation "_".  Remove that and put the declare all on one line and it works for me.

```
myStr = "Declare PtrSafe2 Sub Sleep2 Lib ""xyz"" (x)"
```

results in

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep2 Lib "xyz" (x)
```

Look at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/declare-statement  for the syntax.

Comment: You are correct, looks like " _" line continuation is not recognized. VBE will try to add "()" if I manually type "Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "xyz" _" and move cursor elsewhere. So it looks like the VBE auto correction is messing thing up. I thought the VBE is not kicking in when doing CodeModule??? Is there a way to turn auto correction off when doing AddFromString?